# First of type & Before or After

Tags: html, css

I basically have a menu like it shown below in the HTML code, and I want to add "|" before each "li" within the menu to give it the look of (Home | About | Contact). Everything is working, however, I am having a problem of deleting the "|" from the very first "li" in each "ul" within the menu.

So at the moment my menu is shown like: ( | Home | About | Contact), how do I get rid of the "|" that is on the first "li" element?

currnt CSS:

```
#mainMenu li:before{
content: "|";
color: blue;
}
```

I have tried to give it a class of "first" and then use li.first {contnet:none} but no hope.

```
                 <nav><ul id="mainMenu"><!--Main Menu-->
                    <li class="first"><a href="#">Home</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Intro1.php">Intro 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Intro2.php">Intro 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Intro3.php">Intro 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Vision.php">Vision</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Contacts.php">Contacts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Staff.php">Staff</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Use.php">Use</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Crisis.php">Crisis</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Basics</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Definition1.php">Definition 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Definition2.php">Definition 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Definition3.php">Definition 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Assess1.php">Assess 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Assess2.php">Assess 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Assess3.php">Assess 3</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Need</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="World1.php">World 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="World2.php">World 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="World3.php">World 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Polar1.php">Polar 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Polar2.php">Polar 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Polar2.php">Polar 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="National.php">National 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Nationa2.php">National 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Nationa3.php">National 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Alaska1.php">Alaska 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Alaska2.php">Alaska 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Alaska3.php">Alaska 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Alaska4.php">Alaska 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Fairbanks.php">Fairbanks</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Models</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Durkheim.php">Durkheim</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Joiner.php">Joiner</a></li>
                            <li><a href="nami.php">NAMI</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Mental.php">Mental</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Church.php">Church</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Menninger.php">Menninger</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Weaver-Wright.php">Weaver/Wright</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Approach</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Trees1.php">Trees 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Trees2.php">Tress 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Goals1.php">Goals 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Goals2.php">Goals 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Training1.php">Training 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Training2.php">Training 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Gas1.php">Gas 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Gas2.php">Gas 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Boat1.php">Boat 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Boat2.php">Boat 2</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Library</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Stories.php">Stories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Books.php">Books</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Plays.php">Plays</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Epics.php">Epics</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Movies.php">Movies</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Articles.php">Articles</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Web</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Arctic.php">Arctic</a></li>
                            <li><a href="National.php">National</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Supports.php">Supports</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Reference.php">Reference</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                </ul></nav>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
#mainMenu ul li:first-child:before{
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: @Loai there is no need to override the css later. check my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Change your css to this: (*using sibling selector*)

```
#mainMenu ul li ~ li:before {
   content: "|";
}
```

The above style will be applied to the elements which have previous sibling elements (`li ~ li`). Hence this styling will not be applied to the first `li` element because it doesn't have any previous sibling elements.

Comment: Or use `nth-of-type(n+2)` but yes it really is down to personal preferences.

Answer (score 5):

You can exclude the first element using `:not` pseduo selector.

```
#mainMenu li:not(:first-child):before {
   content: "|";
   color: blue;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uUuVL/1/)

Comment: use `first-child` instead, it has better browser support. but actually, if you use `:not` it becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
#mainMenu li.first:before{
content: none;
}
```

I think this should work.

Comment: It worked, but below there is an answer that can do the job without using or adding class's. Thank you for your help!